# I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with this code

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<?php   
 if ( is_home() ) {

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>


  <div id="post">

      <?php the_content(); ?>

    </div>


    <?php endwhile;?>


    <?php endif; ?>
} else if (is_page() ) {

 $category = get_post_meta($posts[0]->ID, 'category', true);
}
if ($category) {
$cat = get_cat_ID($category);
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$post_per_page = 4; // -1 shows all posts
$do_not_show_stickies = 1; // 0 to show stickies
$args=array(
'category__in' => array($cat),
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'DESC',
'paged' => $paged,
'posts_per_page' => $post_per_page,
'caller_get_posts' => $do_not_show_stickies
  );
  $temp = $wp_query;  // assign orginal query to temp variable for later use   
  $wp_query = null;
  $wp_query = new WP_Query($args); 
   if( have_posts() ) : 
    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>

  <div id="post">

      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>


<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; 

$wp_query = $temp;  

 }  
?>
```

Comment: Can you please give us some more info? What doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: The code you posted should result in a parse error on line 4 (`<?php` within `<?php`).  PHP code goes between `<?php` and `?>`, everything outside is passed through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line #4 you are opening a new PHP block even though the old one hasn't been closed yet.

You'll want to delete the preceding `<?php` on that line. You don't need it.

Additionally:

You have an extra `endwhile;` in your `else` block. The while loop is started and closed within the `if ( is_home() ) {` block.

The code starting with `} else if (is_page() ) {` is not in a PHP block. You should either open a `<?php` block or not close the preceding one.

Answer (score 1):

The first php tag is unclosed.  Close that and move on from there.  It would be easier to read and debug if you thought of it as primarily being a PHP file rather than an HTML file.  That is, keep a php tag open until straight HTML is required.  At that point, close the PHP tag, write your HTML, and reopen a PHP tag.

Answer (score 0):

At the point you do this:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
```

you're still in "php mode" from the first `<?php` at the top of the script, so this line is a syntax error. You cannot embed one `<?php ?>` block inside another.

Remove the `<?php` before the `if`, or add a `?>` after the `is_home()` stuff on earlier line:

```
<?php if (is_home()) { ?>

<?php if ( ...) ?>
```

or

```
<?php
if (is_home()) {
    if (...) { ?>
```

As well, I'd STRONGLY suggest enabling `display_errors` and `error_reporting` in your PHP configuration. If they were on, you'd have see the syntax error caused by the extra `<?php`:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in somefile.php on line XXX
```